# How to be able to use a , (comma) inside a string in Marketing Cloud SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

This query runs just fine in Query Studio:

```
SELECT Id,
'Some string not containing a comma' AS NewColumn
FROM SomeTable
```

And this query gives the error "`Unable to create temporary data extension: Field name cannot contain the character '.`":

```
SELECT Id,
'Some string, containing a comma' AS NewColumn
FROM SomeTable
```

Does anyone have a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) ignore query studio, use Automation studio, and build the respective DE in advance;

[image]

=====

b) escape the comma using `char(44)`

```
SELECT 
a.subscriberKey
,'somestring' + char(44) + 'test' AS newColumn
FROM ENT._subscribers a
```

reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6022/sql-server-char-function-and-reference-guide/

queryStudio result:

[image]

Comment: I was experimenting with queries, the number of fields and types of fields was not yet 100% determined, so Query Studio is perfect for that kind of work. The char(44) trick works there as well. Thanks!